# regex to find string that has two key words but does not include a 3rd one

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Can someone help me to build a regex to find a string that has keyword1 and keyword2 but not keyword3?

I tried this but didn't work:

`/^(?=.*\bkeyword1\b)(?=.*\bkeyword2\b)(?:(?!:keyword3)).*$/`,

many thanks

Comment: Use `/^(?=.*\bkeyword1\b)(?=.*\bkeyword2\b)(?!.*\bkeyword3\b)`

Answer (score 2):

Use two positive lookaheads and one negative lookahead:

```js
[
  'has keyword1 and keyword2 and not 3.',
  'has keyword2 and keyword1 and not 3.',
  'has keyword1 and keyword2 and keyword3.',
  'has keyword3 and keyword2 and keyword1.',
  'has keyword4 and keyword5 but not 1 and 2'
].forEach(str => {
  let m = str.match(/^(?=.*\bkeyword1\b)(?=.*\bkeyword2\b)(?!.*\bkeyword3\b)./);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + (m ? true : false))
});
```

output:

```
has keyword1 and keyword2 and not 3. => true
has keyword2 and keyword1 and not 3. => true
has keyword1 and keyword2 and keyword3. => false
has keyword3 and keyword2 and keyword1. => false
has keyword4 and keyword5 but not 1 and 2 => false
```

Explanation:

- `^` -- anchor at start of string
- `(?=.*\bkeyword1\b)` -- positive lookahead for `keyword1` anywhere in the string
- `(?=.*\bkeyword2\b)` -- positive lookahead for `keyword2` anywhere in the string
- `(?!.*\bkeyword3\b)` -- negative lookahead for `keyword3` anywhere in the string
- `.` -- any single character (to avoid falsy test on empty string)